# How to access Knockout component functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm begin transform part of system in my work in `Knockout Component`, but any time, I need access functions defined in my component.

Example I will create a `msgComponent`:

In Html:

```
<body>
    <msgComponent params="message: 'blablabla'"></msgComponent>
</body>
```

In Js:

```
ko.components.register('msgComponent', {
    viewModel: function (params)
    {
        this.message = ko.observable(params.message);

        this.showMessage = function()
        {
            alert(this.messenge());
        }.bind(this);
    },
    template: '<div data-bind="text: message"></div>'
});


function myMasterViewModel()
{
    var master = this;

    // How to can I access my component this way?
    master.msgComponent = msgComponent;

    master.showMessage();
}
```

Like in my example, how to can I access my component function with other view model?

---

Fist Edit:
@Dandy
If I need instance more `msgComponent` in page, I can define this way?

```
var sharedComponent = function(params){
    var params = params || {};
    this.message = ko.observable(params.message);
    this.showMessage = function()
    {
        alert(this.message());
    }.bind(this);
}

ko.components.register('msgcomponent', {
    viewModel: function(params)
    {
        this.instance = params.viewModel;
    },
    template: '<div data-bind="with: instance"><div data-bind="text: message"></div></div>'
});

function myMasterViewModel()
{
    var master = this;

    master.msg = new sharedComponent({message: 'huahua'});

    master.show = function()
    {
        master.msg.showMessage();
    };
}
```

Or have any more correct way to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `instance` method of component registration. Something like

```
var sharedComponent = function(params){
  var params = params || {};
  this.message = ko.observable(params.message);
  this.showMessage = function()
  {
      alert(this.message());
  }.bind(this);
}

var comShared = new sharedComponent ({message: 'test mssage'});

ko.components.register('msgcomponent', {
    viewModel: {instance: comShared },
    template: '<div data-bind="text: message"></div>'
});

function myMasterViewModel()
{
    var master = this;

    // How to can I access my component this way?
    master.msgComponent = comShared;
    master.msgComponent.showMessage();
}
```

Read more [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-shared-object-instance).

Comment: If I need instance more `msgComponent` in page, how to can I do?

Comment: I edited my question, add code a way I think is work